# CSS not being loaded after form submit - jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, forms, multipage

I have a HTML form which, when submitted, loads a results page.

When I link to the same results page with an anchor tag I can use either `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` which forces a full refresh of the page and reloads the relevant page CSS.

Is there an equivalent for pages loaded from form a submission? I am not currently using jQuery to submit the form.

**NOTE:**

Further to @peterm's answer, which I tried initially without success, I had a parameter appended to the form's action string (`action="results.php?type=search"`) which I moved into a hidden input element inside the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="search" />
```

After doing this it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-ajax="false"` on a `form` element.

According to [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html)

> To submit a form without Ajax, you can either disable Ajax form
>   handling globally, or per form via the data-ajax="false" attribute.
>   The target attribute (as in target="_blank") is respected on forms as
>   well, and will default to the browser's handling of that target when
>   the form submits. Note that unlike anchors, the rel attribute is not
>   allowed on forms.

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply but when I add data-ajax="false" my page doesn't load any content. Am I missing something else?

Comment: It's ok I got it sorted. I had a query parameter appended to the form's action string. I have moved it into a hidden input field.